# Остаётся ли объект класса если не указывается на него ссылка?

Tags: java

Например я использую переопределённый метод equals в аргументы которого нужно написать конструктор new Test(5) и объект будет использоваться один раз, он будет удалён из памяти?

Comment: Да. *(12 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Спасибо (12 символов)

Comment: @Igor вы на какой из вопросов ответили? Который в заголовке или в конце текста?

Comment: @tym32167 Ответ на Ваш вопрос требует продолжительной медитации.

Comment: @Igor надеюсь, вы достигнете просветления и будете знать ответы на все вопросы без подсказок от гномиков :)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-weakhashmap проверьте второй пункт

Answer (score 0):

Если вы будете вызывать переопределенный метод equals, то каждый раз будет создаваться новый объект Test с аргументом конструктора 5.
Удалены будут созданные объекты только тогда, кода память будет заполнена настолько, что сборщик мусора решит пройтись по памяти нашей программы. Т.к. мы не можем самостоятельно инициировать вызов сборщика мусора (кроме как намеренно заполнить память), то, в случае, когда функция может быть вызвана много раз для экономии памяти, лучше записать объект new Test(5) в переменную: Test test = new Test(5).